# Refactor a for() loop using Math.pow()?

Tags: javascript, loops, pow

Here's a question that I'm hoping will improve my programming chops. I have this loop that is calculating a future sum based on annual payments, increased by interest and devalued by inflation (it's derived from the PV function in Excel):

```
var pmt = 66,449.75 // annual payment
var ip = 0.03 // interest rate
var fv = 0 // future value, not require here
var k = 1 // interest is applied at beginning / end of period
var n = 25 // number of periods (years in this case)
var ri = 0.025 // rate of inflation
var pv = 0;    
for (var i = n - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    pv = (pv + (pmt * k - fv) * Math.pow(1 + ri, i)) / (1 + ip);
}
```

Is it possible to use Math.pow() to reproduce what this loop is doing?

Comment: You are recreating pv in each iteration, what you want to archieve?

Comment: what is it doing? I ain't a compiler and your variable naming doesn't help the matter

Comment: your question needs more details. If this is implementing a specific mathematical approach or algorithm, please add information on which one (there might be a completely different, more efficient implementation to reach the same result). Also please make sure your code explains your variables. If this is a copy paste, take the extra effort to rename your variables so that we can understand what they're for, or explain them in your post. Without that, `pmt`, `k`, `fv`, `ri` and `ip` might be constants for all we know, and things like `pmt*k-fv` make no sense inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, I rename some expressions

```js
a = pmt * k - fv;
b = 1 + ri;
c = 1 + ip;
x = pv;
```

So your code becomes

```js
for (var i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    x = x / c + a * Math.pow(b, i) / c;
}
```

Then

```latex
x_0
x_1 = x_0 / c + a b^{n-1} / c
x_2 = x_1 / c + a b^{n-2} / c = x_0 / c^2 + a b^{n-1} / c^2 + a b^{n-2} / c
...
x_i = x_{i-1} / c + a b^{n-i} / c = x_0 / c^i + \sum_{k=1}^i a b^{n-k} / c^{i-k+1}
...
x_n = x_0 / c^n + \sum_{k=1}^n a * b^{n-k} / c^{n-k+1}
```

According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20%2F%20c%5En%20%2B%20%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20a%20*%20b%5E%7Bn-k%7D%20%2F%20c%5E%7Bn-k%2B1%7D),

```latex
x_n = x_0 / c^n + a (b^n-c^n) / (c^n (b-c))
```

Therefore, instead of your loop you can use

```js
var foo = Math.pow(1 + ip, n); // c^n
pv = pv / foo + (pmt*k-fv) * (Math.pow(1+ri,n) - foo) / foo / (ri-ip);
```

Comment: Thanks for going to that effort! However, using this code doesn't produce the same result that mine had previously. Apologies, but as some readers pointed out I did leave out details that may have been critical - which I've added now above.

Comment: When I compare yours vs. mine side by side, your code produces the value 125046905.28783791, and mine produces 184770003.67224348.

Comment: @stylecramper Using `pmt = 66449.75` (`66,449.75` throws), I get `1522310.2610685586` with your code and `1522310.2610685711` with mine. That small difference of `1.25e-8` is normal because of precision errors.

Comment: @stylecramper Not at all :) Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.